# Echo ps while preserving newlines?

Tags: bash, process, newline, ps

If I do `ps ax` in Terminal, the result will be like this:

```
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
    1   ??  Ss     2:23.26 /sbin/launchd
   10   ??  Ss     0:08.34 /usr/libexec/kextd
   11   ??  Ss     0:48.72 /usr/sbin/DirectoryService
   12   ??  Ss     0:26.93 /usr/sbin/notifyd
```

While if I do `echo $(ps ax)`, I get:

```
PID TT STAT TIME COMMAND 1 ?? Ss 2:23.42 /sbin/launchd 10 ?? Ss 0:08.34 /usr/libexec/kextd 11 ?? Ss 0:48.72 /usr/sbin/DirectoryService 12 ?? Ss 0:26.93 /usr/sbin/notifyd
```

Why?

And how do I preserve the newlines and tab characters?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Same way as always: use quotes.

```
echo "$(ps ax)"
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply use double-quotes in the variable that is being echo'd

```
echo "$(ps ax)"
```

this will do it without all that extra junk coding or hassle.

edit: ugh... someone beat me to it! lol

Answer (score 3):

That's because `echo` isn't piping at all--it's interpreting the output of `ps ax` as a variable, and (unquoted) variables in bash essentially compress whitespace--including newlines.

If you want to pipe the output of `ps`, then pipe it:

```
ps ax | ... (some other program)
```

Comment: Ok, say i want to do `ps ax | grep foobar` it still messes the design up.

Comment: I use that construct all the time, and it works great for me. If you think the output is incorrect when actually piping, please provide additional details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to have line-by-line access:

```
readarray psoutput < <(ps ax)

# e.g.
for line in "${psoutput[@]}"; do echo -n "$line"; done
```

This requires a recent(ish) bash version

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about *piping* the output? Your question says "pipe", but your example is a command substitution:

```
ps ax | cat  #Yes, it's useless, but all cats are...
```

More useful?

```
ps ax | while read ps_line
do
   echo "The line is '$ps_line'"
done
```

If you're talking about [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), you need quotes as others have already pointed out in order to force the shell not to throw away whitespace:

```
echo "$(ps ax)"
foo="$(ps ax)"
```